# Save and restore the size and position of a window in Gtk#

Tags: mono, gtk#

I would like to save and restore the size and position of the window between program launches.
What is the most correct and compatible way in Gtk# to:

1. Get current size and position of the particular window.
2. Set the size and position of the window.

Answer (score 4):

To get the location and dimensions of a window you can call [Window.GetPosition()](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aGtk.Window.GetPosition%28System.Int32@,System.Int32@%29) [Window.GetSize()](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aGtk.Window.GetSize%28System.Int32@,System.Int32@%29)

To set the position of a window you can call [Window.SetPosition()](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aGtk.Window.SetPosition%28Gtk.WindowPosition%29) and [Window.Move()](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aGtk.Window.Move%28System.Int32,System.Int32%29)

To set the size of a window you can call [Window.Resize()](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aGtk.Window.Resize%28System.Int32,System.Int32%29)